# Couldn't use function posix_memalign in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm trying to  use the function posix_memalign in visual studio but it always has the error "posix_memalign': identifier not found"

Here is my simple program:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(){
  double *pointer;
  int result;
  result = posix_memalign((void **)&pointer, 128, 128);
  printf("%d",result);
  getch();
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28v=vs.120%29.aspx (`_aligned_malloc` and `_aligned_free`)

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not support posix. There should be Windows API's that you can use.

Comment: can i execute it in Linux..Is there any conditions to do that?